# Bitshift Multiplication

Tags: bit-shift, multiplication

**question**

Can someone help me figure out what `37 * x` is only using one line of code also only using bit shifts and adding?

**tested**

What I thought it was is `(x<<5) + (x<<2)` + x because of:

```
37 = 32 + 4 + 1
```

which is basically `2^5 + 2^2 + 2^0`

I was told this is wrong. Can someone please explain why? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you're restricted to integral types, it is correct, which can be empirically verified by simply evaluating `37 * x` and `(x<<5) + (x<<2) + x` for several random `x`. What justification did "they" give when "they" told you it was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is right but maybe you have to take a look on your used datatypes. So that the bitshifting operations don't cause a overflow and some information of your word is shifted out of the variable. For example if you have an 8-Bit number 10d:

```
0000 1010 << 5 --> 1 0100 0000
```

This number does not fit a 8 Bit number so the result would be

```
0100 0000
```

Which is a different value than you expected. If you give us more details about your implementation we can have a look at that.